# Book about a boy who easily sees through regular magic tricks, but then finds a magician who can use real magic

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I’m trying to find a book about a boy who hates his birthday, because every time his parents bring him a magician, he can just see through their tricks. Then he finds one magician who actually has magic and goes to the park near there with his little sister and they find out it’s also real magic!

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, was the story set in the modern world? And do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I remember I read this back in 2012 and I don’t remeber when it was published. The setting was in the modern world and the cover looked like the mc running in the park